# How to concat porpery value with string in mule 4

Tags: spring, mule, anypoint-studio

I need dynamic flow name in mule 4. I done below one in mule 3 and its not supporting mule 4. how can I do this?

```
<flow-ref name="${igate.membership}-membership-flow" doc:name="External Membership Flow" />
```

In my property file [igate.properties],

```
igate.membership=ebet
```

And my Spring beans,

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <spring:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
            <spring:property name="location" value="igate.properties"/>
        </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @aled 'Unknown flow name'

Comment: What's the value of the property ${igate.membership} if you add a logger before the flow reference?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I suggested?

Comment: @aled yes tried that. but not worked. I'm able to use other property values in that property file. the problem is '${igate.membership}-membership-flow' here string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use the [configuration properties](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/configuring-properties#properties-files) configuration element instead of the Spring bean, example `<configuration-properties file="igate.properties"/>`. I don't think you can use a Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean directly as property placeholders in Mule 4.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand what failed.